# CEIL in objective function CPLEX C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cplex

As per my knowledge, there's a tutorial that shows that ILOG can use ceil function ([here](https://cs.pwr.edu.pl/zielinski/lectures/om/opl/workbook.pdf)). However, when I tried to implement it to calculate my objective function in CPLEX C++ (concert), it was failed. What I am looking for is as per below:

```
for (i=0; i<I; i++){
  for (j=0; j<J; j++){
      TO += ceil(DecisionVariable[i][j]/parameter[j]);
  }
}
```

Any advises would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OPL we have ceil but in concert C++ the equivalent function is IloCeil.

But we need to remember that this function is not linear.

In [How to with OPL ?](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/) we can read [How to use ceil of a decision variable in a CPLEX constraint](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/ceil.mod) ?

```
range r=1..4;

float x[r]=[1.5,4.0,2.0001,5.9999];

dvar int y[r];
dvar float f[r] in 0..0.9999999;

subject to
{
forall(i in r) y[i]==x[i]+f[i];


}

execute
{
writeln(x," ==> ",y);
}

assert forall(i in r) y[i]==ceil(x[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the document you mentioned is too much. I couldn't quickly locate the content you are referencing. Please point out their location. But as far as I know, ceil is a round-up function, please check:

1. Does the code contain the header files needed by the ceil function?
2. Whether the parameters of the ceil function are set correctly？
3. If you use a function as a parameter, make sure that the return value of the function is double.

Comment: Thank you @YujianYao .. the ceil function is derived from decision variable and parameter, and the transition from IloExpr to double is somewhat still problematic for me.. could you please give some example?